# TFS 2005: Sharepoint site not working

Tags: tfs, tfs-2005

I've just created a new Test instance of TFS 2005 SP1 and migrated the databases.  The TFS part seems to work correctly, but the Sharepoint site doesn't seem to work.

http://TfsServer/sites/Project1/default.aspx gives a 404 error.

Also heading to Sharepoint Central Administration --> Manage Site collection owners and entering the above site name under 'Web Site URL' gives the following error message:
'The virtual server that is referenced here is not in the config database"

The config database is the only one I did not restore from the source (following instructions here).  How do I go about recreating the Sharepoint site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Sharepoint Central Admin
- Manage Web Server List
- click on server name
- Configure Virtual Server settings
- Default Web site
- Manage Content Databases
- Click on STS_Content_TFS
- Note the values in textboxes.
- Check Remove content database and click on OK.
- Recreate content database with the same name (STS_Content_TFS) and other information
  as above.